# Internet Explorer: Disable Access from Visitors

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, web, browser

Is there a way to disable the access to my website when someone is browsing with IE? Best would be to redirect them to a nice landing-page where you explain why access is not possible.

I'm using Laravel for my project =).

Cheers,
Stan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

PHP have function `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` used to identify browser

```
 if(using_ie())
 {
   //redirect
 }
function using_ie() 
    { 
        $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
        $ub = False; 
        if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $ub = True; 
        } 

        return $ub; 
    }
```

you can also use

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false) {
  header('Location: /index-ie.php');
  exit;
}
```